# How to use Package in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, web, ssl-certificate

I try to check "SSL Certificate" with Spatie\SslCertificate\SslCertificate but it doesn't work.
I try it in laravel 7.6.0
I try all things like do "composer update" and do "auto-load (because is automated by composer maybe (?))"

So, the error is `Undefined type 'Spatie\SslCertificate\SslCertificate'.intelephense(1009)` 
But i have declare the package in my class like this `use Spatie\SslCertificate\SslCertificate;`

Did i miss some steps in here or something else?

This is my full code in DorController class;

```
 <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Spatie\SslCertificate\SslCertificate;
    
    class DorController extends Controller
    {
        public function yeah_1(){
            $certificate = SslCertificate::createForHostName('spatie.be');
return $certificate->isValid();
        }
    
    }
```

This is my composer.json (is completly no bugs)

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2.5",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "spatie/ssl-certificate": "^1.22"
},
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
}
```

}

I am sorry if this question is so basic or stupid
I really sorry for it

Comment: Where does the `intelephense(1009)` come from?

Comment: `spatie/ssl-certificate` requires at least php 8, it probably gives an error when you ran: `composer require spatie/ssl-certificate`? Source: https://github.com/spatie/ssl-certificate/blob/main/composer.json